# Scrollbar while slide transition with jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have 2 pages embedded on my single HTML file. so what it does is that initially it shows PAGE1, then if i swipe from right to left OR left to right PAGE2 should show. One slide transition is reversed, the other not. Problem is that on the not reversed slide a little scrollbar is appearing on the bottom of the screen. That happens only if i use it on android.

does anybody know this problem?

```
    $(document).swipeleft(function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('#second',{
            transition: 'slide', 
            reverse: false,
            changeHash: false
        });
    })

    $(document).swiperight(function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('#first',{
            transition: 'slide', 
            reverse: true,
            changeHash: false
        });
    })
```

thank you!

Comment: if a scrollbar is popping up, you will need to show us your CSS.  At first read, it sounds like something that CSS would be controlling.  You might have to write `overflow:hidden` somewhere